# What is the difference between the probability law of X and the distribution of X?

Tags: probability-theory

I am a bit confused.

The probability law regarding a random variable is defined as mapping $\mathcal{P} : \mathbb{B} \to [0,1]$, where $\mathbb{B}$ is the regular Borel set; that is, a probability law is an image measure.

On the other hand, the probability distribution is $\mathbb{D} : \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is defined as $\mathbb{D}(x) = P(\omega | X (\omega) < x)$.

Although they are very similar, they are not equivalent, since the latter has a very specific structure, but, in the former, one can find the measure of any Borel set. Why, then, do a lot of texts informally claim that they are the, in fact, equivalent?

It is clear that, for any measurable function, for example, a random variable, one can write its distribution using the probability law mapping, but, conversely, for example, assigning a probability measure to an arbitrary Borel set using the distribution function is not very clear to me.

I have never taken a formal course on probability theory, so forgive me if this question seems too stupid, or does not make much sense.

Comment: You should start by saying what $\mathbb B$ and $X$ is before using them. For example, if $X$ is a set, then $X(\omega)$ doesn't make sense, while if $X$ is a function then $\mathbb D:X\to[0,1]$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews My bad. Does the question make sense now?

Comment: Probability law of X = Law of X = Distribution of X.

Comment: @Did Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The distribution or the law of a random variable $X$ is a probability measure $\mathcal L$ on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal R)$, where $\mathcal R$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$, such that $\mathcal L:\mathcal R\to[0,1]$. The cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a random variable $X$ is the function $F_X:\mathbb R\to[0,1]$ such that $F_X(x)=\Pr\{X\le x\}$ for $x\in\mathbb R$. If we know the distribution of the random variable $X$, then we also know the CDF of the random variable $X$. It also true that the CDF uniquely determines the distribution of the random variable $X$ (see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136658/why-does-a-cumulative-distribution-function-cdf-uniquely-define-a-distribution)).

I hope this helps.

Comment: so I think I was getting confused between the distribution and the cumulative distribution function of a random variable X. So the conclusion is that CDF gives me all the probability from $(-\infty , x)$ where as the distribution function is computing the probability measure of any  arbitrary borel set in the sigma algebra

Comment: @user3503589 Yes, you are precisely right. But if you know the CDF of the random variable $X$, you can also determine the measure of any borel set.

Comment: But then it could be very nasty to use just the cdf to actually compute the measure of a pathological borel set. By pathological i mean say countable union of measurable sets....

Comment: @user3503589 Indeed. Your very right (and too rare on this forum) intuition is that the basic object is the distribution, not its translation in terms of CDF.